# Can jQuery UI Dialog Box hold a video? (maybe a youtube video?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, video, containers

I haven't seen any examples on the net.  Was wondering if someone knows if there's one that exists or if it's even possible.

thanx

Answer (score 2):

I just edited the dialog on http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ with Firebug and was able to get an embedded video to play just fine. I replaced the text within the p tag with the youtube embed code.

Comment: Your answer has "expired"... "this page" you link to no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

See this plugin http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery_youtube/

Answer (score 0):

You could use facebox too...

Find it here: [get facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox)